# Prove $\det \left[\begin{smallmatrix} A&B\\\\C&D\\ \end{smallmatrix}\right] =\det(AD-BC)$ for $A,B,C,D$ upper triangular complex matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, block-matrices

> Let $A,B,C$ and $D$ be upper-triangular $n \times n$ complex matrices. Let
>
> $$E=\begin{bmatrix} A&B\\C&D\\ \end{bmatrix}$$
>
> Prove $\det(E)=\det(AD-BC)$.

I did this problem in the case that the matrices commute but I cannot figure out this case.

Comment: Can you include what you did when the matrices commuted?

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to prove the identity when the upper triangular parts of $A,B,C,D$ are independent indeterminates (alternatively, prove the identity for invertible $D$ first, then pass $D$ to the limit). Try to justify the first equality below using properties of [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement) (see also [this Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices)) and the second equality below using the condition that $A,B,C,D$ are triangular:
$$
\det(E)
=\det(A-BD^{-1}C)\det(D)
=\det(A-BCD^{-1})\det(D)
=\det(AD-BC).
$$
(**Edit.** The following part is wrong. See darij grinberg's comment.) <del>You may also try to prove that in Leibniz formula for determinant of $E$, only two generalised diagonals of $E$ are non-vanishing, one given by the main diagonal and the other formed by the diagonals of $B$ and $D$. But I find this argument harder to be worded clearly.</del>

Comment: "only two generalised diagonals of $E$ are non-vanishing": This is not true. I think $2^n$ generalized diagonals should be non-vanishing. The easiest way to get the determinant combinatorially looks like the following: Permute the rows and the columns of $E$ in such a way that the matrix becomes block-triangular with $2 \times 2$-blocks. (The permutation is $\left[1,3,5,\ldots,2n-1,2,4,6,\ldots,2n\right]$ in one-line notation, or its inverse.) Then, its determinant becomes $\prod_{i=1}^n \left(a_i d_i - b_i c_i\right)$, where $a_i, b_i, c_i, d_i$ are the diagonal entries of $A, B, C, D$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg You are right. I stand corrected. Perhaps you may elaborate your comment into an answer.