# What are the eigenvalues of $\begin{pmatrix} A & B \\ B &-A \end{pmatrix}$ in terms of $A$ and $B$?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, block-matrices

It is known that the set of eigenvalues of the following block matrix

$$ C = \begin{pmatrix} A & B \\ B & A \end{pmatrix} $$

is the union of the eigenvalues of the matrices $A + B$ and $A - B$. I am interested in the matrix of the following form

$$ C = \begin{pmatrix} A & B \\ B &-A \end{pmatrix} $$

Is there a description of the eigenvalues of $C$ in terms of $A$ and $B$?

**Edit.** If $AB=BA$, then we can do the following.
$$ 
C = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
A & B \\ B &-A \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 
v \\ u \end{pmatrix} =\lambda \begin{pmatrix} 
v \\ u \end{pmatrix}
$$
implies
$$
\left\{
  \begin{array}{l}
    Av+Bu=\lambda v \\
    Bv-Au=\lambda u 
  \end{array}.
\right.
$$
By multiplying the first equation by $B$ and assuming $AB=BA$, we get
$$
(A^2+B^2)u=\lambda^2u.
$$
Therefore, $\lambda^2$ is an eigenvalue of $A^2+B^2$, what is discussed in the comments.

Comment: $\pm \sqrt{A^2+B^2}$, but this has sense only if $A,B$ are symmetric

Comment: @Exodd A,B are symmetric, but what do you mean by $\sqrt{A^2+B^2}$? Eigenvalues of the matrix $\sqrt{A^2+B^2}$?

Comment: @QMath: Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $C$.  Then $\det (C-\lambda I) = 0$, and expanding that gives you $\lambda^2I = A^2 + B^2$.   So, $\lambda^2$ is an eigenvalue of $A^2 + B^2$.

Comment: @Dan If that were true, it would imply $A^2+B^2$ is always a scalar multiple of $I$ for any $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @aschepler I think he meant $det(\lambda^2I - A^2 - B^2) = 0$

Comment: @Exodd This holds in the case $AB=BA$, but not in general.

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2416817/173147, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/706513/173147, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3264807/173147

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer when $A$ has inverse $A^{-1}$. Use the formula for the determinant of block-partitioned matrices in terms of [Schur's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement#Properties). If $(A-\lambda I)$ has an inverse then $\det(A-\lambda I)\neq 0$
\begin{align}
\det \left(\begin{bmatrix} A&B \\ B& -A \end{bmatrix}-\lambda\begin{bmatrix} I&0 \\ 0& I 
\end{bmatrix} \right) 
=&
\det \left(\begin{bmatrix} A-\lambda\cdot I&B \\ B& -A-\lambda\cdot I \end{bmatrix}\right) 
\\
=& 
\det(-A-\lambda I) \cdot \det\left(-(A-\lambda I) - B(A-\lambda I)^{-1} B\right)
\end{align}

Thus, the eigenvalues of $\begin{bmatrix} A&B\\ B&-A \end{bmatrix} $ would be between the eigenvalues of $-A$ and between the roots of the equation
$$
\det\left(-(A-\lambda I) - B(A-\lambda I)^{-1} B\right)=0
$$